# Getting info from UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` and I ask the user to input some data using the number pad.

- Is the data that comes out a string or an integer?
- How do I multiply the number they input by 10 then output it to a label?

Answer (score 37):

Just use the `text` attribute of the `UITextField` to get the value (which is a String).

Then, use the `toInt()` method (which returns an optional) to convert that to an Integer, so that you can perform mathematical operations.

```
@IBOutlet weak var field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func getVal () {
     var text: String = field.text
     var multipliedNum: Int = 0

     if let num = text.toInt() {
         multipliedNum = num * 10
     }

     label.text = "\(multipliedNum)"
}
```

Comment: `label.text = "\(multipliedNum)"`

Comment: Just for fun, here's the one-liner: `label.text = "\((field.text.toInt() ?? 0) * 10)"`

Comment: If you need it, there's also NSValueTransformer which you can use to do some fancier parsing if you ever need to handle 1.3E-3 for instance.

Answer (score 5):

Xcode 9 with Swift

```
//Get reference of UITextView
@IBOutlet weak var inputMealName: UITextField! 

//Get value of input from UITextView in variable
let name: String = inputMealName.text!

//Use input value eg. show alert
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: name, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the string via the UITextField attribute.

- the data comes out a string. You can use string methods(intValue , doubleValue....etc) convert string value to a number.
- when you get the number , you can set the label output via its text attribute.