# how to assign textfield value to variable on Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

how to assign text field value to variable on Xcode?
example of what I want to do :
in the picture, I create a tow text field: textone and texttow
I want to take the value that the user entered and assign it to a variable, then for example I want to print the variable that it has the string that user entered[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXNFZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an IBAction to your code that's connected to your textfield in interface builder. Then use `textfield.text` to access the textfield's text property and use `print()` to print the value.

Also, this looks like a previous issue: [Getting info from UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859986/getting-info-from-uitextfield/25860217).